# How to make a function return both a promise and a callback

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Today, when I was working with node, I met some special async functions with "overloads" that accept both promises and callbacks. Like this:

```
doSomething(result => {
  console.log(result)
})

doSomething()
  .then(result => console.log(result))
```

And probably this:

```
const result = await doSomething()
console.log(result)
```

I tried to implement this in my code but was unsuccessful. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you had a function that was going to read your config file and parse it and you wanted to support both versions.  You could do that like this with two separate implementation inside.  Note, this has full error handling and uses the nodejs calling convention for the callback that passes parameters `(err, result)`:

```
function getConfigData(filename, callback) {
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
       fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
            try {
                if (err) throw err;
                let result = JSON.parse(data);
                callback(null, result);
            } catch(e) {
                callback(err);
            }
       });
    } else {
       return fs.promises.readFile(filename).then(data => {
           return JSON.parse(data);
       }).
    }
}
```

This could then be used as either:

```
getConfigData('./config.json').then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});

configData('./config.json', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Depending upon the specific asynchronous operation, it may be better or more efficient to have two separate implementations internally or to have one implementation that you adapt at the end to either a callback or a promise.

And, there's a useful helper function if you adapt a promise to a callback in multiple places like this:

```
function callbackHelper(p, callback) {
   if (typeof callback === "function") {
       // use nodejs calling convention for callbacks
       p.then(result => {
           callback(null, result);
       }, err => {
           callback(err);
       });
    } else {
       return p;
    }
}
```

That lets you work up a simpler shared implementation:

```
function getConfigData(filename, callback) {
   let p = fs.promises.readFile(filename).then(data => {
       return JSON.parse(data);
   });
   return callbackHelper(p, callback);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I've got the answer working.

Comment: @EthanLal - Are you handling errors properly?  I wrote this answer to be a more complete answer than Lionel's because that answer does not teach proper error handling and does not teach the proper use of the nodejs calling convention for the callback and does not show a flexible helper function that can be used when you're doing this more than once all of which are important.  For example, if the promise in Lionel's implementation rejects, that implementation does nothing.  It does not communicate an error back via the callback.  That is required!

Comment: @EthanLal - If you're relatively new here and new to your topic, then be careful about just going with the first answer you see here that seems like it might work.  Evaluate all answers that you see in the first few hours and decide which one teaches you the best approach to the problem.  I generally wait at least 4 hours before accepting an answer to my questions in the hope that someone might provide an even better answer.  Of course, you can always change your best answer selection at any time, but once you mark one as the best answer, it's not very likely you will get more answers.

Comment: You're right, I'm new here. I'll do that.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, I'll do my research and start fresh.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a function like this by creating a promise, then chaining on that promise with the argument if there is one, and then returning that chained promise. That will make it call the callback at the appropriate time, as well as giving you access to the promise that will complete when the callback completes. If you want the original promise even when there's a callback (not the chained version), then you can return that instead, by still chaining but then returning the original promise instead.

```js
function f(cb) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(123), 1000);
    });
    if (cb) {
        return promise.then(cb);
    } else {
        return promise;
    }
}

// usage 1
f(console.log)

// usage 2
f().then(console.log)
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you show the code of ^, please?

Comment: Here you go! :)

Comment: Your code example does not have proper error handling and you're not using the nodejs calling convention with the callback with args like this `(err, val)`.  You should assume any promise could reject and should pass the error back to the callback if the caller is using the callback.

Comment: @jfriend00 To be honest, I've never used node before, so I don't really know exactly what you mean. If you edit my answer, will it let me accept those changes?

Comment: @EthanLal Glad you got it working! Could you please mark my answer as accepted?

Comment: @EthanLal Sorry, could you clarify what you mean by that? If you don't pass an argument then cb will be undefined, which is falsy, so the original promise will just get directly returned.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unaccepting your answer, I'll need some more research to do that.