# Asyncronicity in a reduce() function WITHOUT using async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, reduce

I am patching the exec() function to allow subpopulating in Mongoose, which is why I am not able to use `async/await` here -- my function will be chained off a db call, so there is no opportunity to call await on it, and within the submodule itself, there I can't add `async/await` outside of an async function itself.

With that out of the way, let's look at what I'm trying to do. I have two separate arrays (`matchingMealPlanFoods` and `matchingMealPlanRecipeFoods`) full of IDs that I need to populate. Both of them reside on the same array, `foods`. They each require a db call with aggregation, and the problem in my current scenario is that only one of the arrays populates because they are happening asynchronously.

What I am trying to do now is use the `reduce` function to return the updated foods array to the next run of `reduce` so that when the final result is returned, I can replace the entire `foods` array once on my `doc`. The problem of course is that my `aggregate/exec` has not yet returned a value by the time the `reduce` function goes into its next run. Is there a way I can achieve this without `async/await` here? I'm including the high-level structure here so you can see what needs to happen, and why using `.then()` is probably not viable.

EDIT: Updating code with async suggestion

```
function execute(model, docs, options, lean, cb) {
  options = formatOptions(options);
  let resolvedCount = 0;
  let error = false;

  (async () => {
    for (let doc of docs) {
      let newFoodsArray = [...doc.foods];
      for (let option of options) {
        const path = option.path.split(".");
        // ... various things happen here to prep the data
        const aggregationOptions = [
          // // $match, then $unwind, then $replaceRoot
        ];

        await rootRefModel
          .aggregate(aggregationOptions)
          .exec((err, refSubDocuments) => {
            // more stuff happens
            console.log('newFoodsArray', newFoodsArray); // this is to check whether the second iteration is using the updated newFoods Array
            const arrToReturn = newFoodsArray.map((food) => {
              const newMatchingArray = food[nests[1]].map((matchingFood) => {
                //more stuff
                return matchingFood;
              });

              const updatedFood = food;
              updatedFood[`${nests[1]}`] = newMatchingArray;
              return updatedFood;
            });
            console.log('arrToReturn', arrToReturn);
            newFoodsArray = [...arrToReturn];
          });
      }
    };
    console.log('finalNewFoods', newFoodsArray); // this should log after the other two, but it is logging first.
    const document = doc.toObject();
    document.foods = newFoodsArray;

    if (resolvedCount === options.length) cb(null, [document]);
  }
})()
```

EDIT: Since it seems it will help, here is the what is calling the `execute` function I have excerpted above.

```
 /**
   * This will populate sub refs
   * @param {import('mongoose').ModelPopulateOptions[]|
   * import('mongoose').ModelPopulateOptions|String[]|String} options
   * @returns {Promise}
   */
  schema.methods.subPopulate = function (options = null) {
    const model = this.constructor;
    if (options) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => execute(model, [this], options, false, (err, docs) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        return resolve(docs[0]);
      }));
    }
    Promise.resolve();
  };
};
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing here. At the end of each iteration of the outer loop you create a `document` object, but if it is not the last iteration, your code does nothing with `document` and it immediately gets out of its (block) scope, together with the `newFoodsArray`, so that information is lost.

Comment: `.reduce()` is really just not very compatible with asynchronous operations because it's loop is synchronous and never pauses for asynchronous operations.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid `async/await`?  It was added to the language because it substantially simplifies asynchronous programming.  It's like you have a task to pound in a nail, someone hands you hammer and you refuse to use the tool designed for the job.

Comment: @trincot This is not the full module file. I mentioned in the first paragraph that I am patching a Mongoose command (really what I'm doing is extending/modifying a 3rd party library). I've added the function that directly calls the execute if that helps.

Comment: @jfriend00 I explained in the first paragraph why I can't use async/await -- you can't use them if the function itself isn't an async function, and I can't make it an async function if it's chained off a Mongoose command.

Comment: Just write your function using `async`/`await` if you know that's going to work, then provide a wrapper that converts the promise back to callback style for compatibility.

Comment: *"This is not the full module file."*: it doesn't have to be, and we prefer that code is kept to the minimum, but still enough to reproduce the problem. However, it should be self-consistent. Creating `document`s and then throwing them immediately away is not really helping us to write a fix for your code. Secondly, I don't see any connection between the code block you had provided and the new one. You introduce `execute()`, but it was nowhere defined.

Comment: The code I included is all within the `execute()` function. The document is not being thrown away, it's being passed to the callback in the last line.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the suggestion, what would this look like?

Comment: @ipenguin67 Exactly like Mike just suggested. Or like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65930993/1048572)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks -- I hadn't refreshed, but I'm struggling to figure out exactly where to put the async/await so that it actually returns. Right now my get request is hanging.

Comment: Thanks -- I updated the code above

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans This is still not quite working. I added some logging above so you can see the timing of everything. If we are truly awaiting the aggregation and exec calls, I would expect the finalNewFoods log to happen last, but it is logging this first, followed by the newFoodsArray and arrToReturn logs. Additionally, the GET request is still hanging and not receiving a response

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans rootRefModel is the result of `mongoose.model(myModel)` and exec patches into Mongoose exec (added to the code above -- this code is the part from a 3rd party library btw)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That makes sense, but I'm still confused a bit by which one needs to be wrapped.

Comment: I've deleted my comments and posted you an answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use async/await just fine here, as long as we remember that `async` is the same as "returning a Promise" and `await` is the same as "resolving a Promise's .then or .catch".

So let's turn all those "synchronous but callback-based" calls into awaitables: your outer code has to keep obeying the API contract, but since it's not meant to a return a value, we can safely mark our own version of it as `async`, and then we can use `await` in combination with promises around any other callback based function calls in our own code just fine:

```js
async function execute(model, docs, options, lean, andThenContinueToThis) {
  options = formatOptions(options);
  let option, resolvedCount = 0;

  for (let doc of docs) {
    let newFoodsArray = [...doc.foods];

    for (option of options) {
      // ...things happen here...

      const aggregationOptions = [/*...data...*/];

      try {
        const refSubDocuments = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => rootRefModel
          .aggregate(aggregationOptions)
          .exec((err, result) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(result));
        // ...do some work based on refSubDocuments...
      }

      // remember to forward errors and then stop:
      catch (err) {
        return andThenContinueToThis(err);
      }
    }

    // remember: bind newFoodsArray somewhere so it doesn't get lost next iteration
  }

  // As our absolutely last action, when all went well, we trigger the call forwarding:
  andThenContinueToThis(null, dataToForward);
}
```